# html-duration-picker is not presented in the correct format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement an external library that allows me to enter the length of a document.

I am using the html-duration-picker library but the input is not working properly for duration.

Did I miss an import or is the library having problems?

Can someone help me?

Thank you

[**Library**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-duration-picker)

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqc4ly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<h2>Result:</h2>
Regular Input box <br><code>&#x3C;input type="text"&#x3E;</code> <br>
<input type="text">
<br><br>
Duration Input box <br><code>&#x3C;input class="html-duration-picker"&#x3E;</code> <br>
<input type="text" class="html-duration-picker">
<br><br>
Hide Seconds <br><code>&#x3C;input class="html-duration-picker" data-hide-seconds&#x3E;</code> <br>
<input type="text" class="html-duration-picker" data-hide-seconds>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to init it (I read this in the documentation of the provided library):

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import * as HtmlDurationPicker from 'html-duration-picker';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    HtmlDurationPicker.init();
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the updated stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ykqpss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts